# relative homotopy and constant map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Take $X$ topological space, $A$ a subset, $x\in A$ point. If $[f]=0$ in $\pi_{n}(X,A,x)$ we could see that exists a deformation of $f$ in $g$ such that $\partial D ^n  $ is fixed during the homotopy and $g$ take values in $A$. It's true the reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In that case you have $[f] = [g]$ where $g(D^n) \subset A$. Now define
$$H : D^n \times I \to X, H(x,t) = g((1-t)x + t s_0)$$
where $s_0 \in \partial D^n$ is the basepoint in $(D^n, \partial D^n,s_0)$. Then $H(z,0) = g(z), H(z,1) = g(s_0) = x$ for all $z \in D^n$ and $H(s_0,t) = g(s_0) = x$ for all $t \in I$. Moreover all $H(x,t) \in A$, thus $g : (D^n, \partial D^n,s_0) \to (X,A,x)$ is homotopic the the constant map $c :  (D^n, \partial D^n,s_0) \to (X,A,x)$ via a homotopy of pointed pairs.